# Extract dendrogram from seaborn clustermap

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn, dendrogram

Given the following example which is from: https://python-graph-gallery.com/404-dendrogram-with-heat-map/

It generates a dendrogram where I assume that it is based on scipy.

```
# Libraries
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Data set
url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df = df.set_index('model')
del df.index.name
df

# Default plot
sns.clustermap(df)
```

Question: How can one get the dendrogram in non-graphical form?

Background information:
From the root of that dendrogram I want to cut it at the largest length. For example we have one edge from the root to a left cluster (L) and an edge to a right cluster (R) ...from those two I'd like to get their edge lengths and cut the whole dendrogram at the longest of these two edges.

Best regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`clustermap` returns a handle to the `ClusterGrid` object, which includes child objects for each dendrogram, 
h.dendrogram_col and h.dendrogram_row. 
Inside these are the dendrograms themselves, which provides the dendrogram geometry
as per the scipy.hierarchical.dendrogram return data, from which you could compute 
the lengths of a specific branch.

```
h = sns.clustermap(df)
dgram = h.dendrogram_col.dendrogram
D = np.array(dgram['dcoord'])
I = np.array(dgram['icoord'])

# then the root node will be the last entry, and the length of the L/R branches will be
yy = D[-1] 
lenL = yy[1]-yy[0]
lenR = yy[2]-yy[3]
```

The linkage matrix, the input used to compute the dendrogram, might also help:

```
h.dendrogram_col.linkage
h.dendrogram_row.linkage
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed elaboration, this helped me to solve the problem!